# Fill image with a repeatable texture

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Would it be possible to fill a png with transparency with a pattern (a repeatable texture)?

Here's a quick example of loading an image onto the canvas, just not sure how to fill it with a pattern, if that isn't possible then would there be a way to extract a path from the png?

```
<script>
    var c = document.getElementById("a");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

   var test= new Image();
    test.src = "images/test.png";
    test.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(test, 0, 0);
    };
</script>

<body>
    <canvas id="a"></canvas>
</body>
```

I've also created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergeh/G8egW/) with an actual loaded png

This is the effect I'm looking to achieve
[image]

### Update

working example based on Simon Sarris' answer
http://jsfiddle.net/sergeh/G8egW/6/

Comment: what do you mean apply a pattern to it?

Comment: by pattern I mean a repeatable texture, same way you can apply a pattern to a shape, see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-createpattern

Comment: I've rephrased the question, hope it clears the confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, draw the image to Canvas.

Then do `globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';`

Then draw the pattern. It will only exist where the image was.

http://jsfiddle.net/G8egW/2/

If you had stuff already on the canvas before this time, you'll need to do the above operations on an in-memory canvas and then draw that canvas to your normal canvas. Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/G8egW/5/

(notice the difference in the grid)

Comment: that seems to work nicely but with your method would there be a way to let a user change the texture? Since the second canvas is in-memory, it's content doesn't appear until it's drawn to the normal canvas but I'd like to be able to change the texture on the fly... Not sure if I'm making any sense, I'm still pretty new at everything canvas

Comment: nevermind, I must be really tired, I just need to actually append the new canvas to the body and use absolute positioning to have them overlay. +1 for your quick answer, I'll do some more testing and accept your answer